# How to create every exported link in a new line to a text document | Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
file = open('mylinks.txt', 'w')
driver.get("website_url")

link_mix = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/a')

for linked in link_mix:
    file.write(linked.get_attribute('href'))
```

The above code scrapes the links and exports them to a text box but they are all just a continuous paragraph. How do i break them into lines for each link

Answer (score 1):

Change this line -

```
file.write(str(link.get_attribute("href")) + "\n"))
```